# how to fix Scapy "Warning pcapy API does not permit to get capure file descriptor"?

Tags: python-2.7, packet-capture, scapy

I am trying to capture outgoing packets (i.e., from my localhost) by using `Scapy` capturing function `sniff`, then parse them as they get captured but I keep getting the following warning:

```
WARNING: fileno: pcapy API does not permit to get capure file descriptor. Bugs ahead! Press  
Enter to trigger packet reading
```

Is there a fix for this issue? I need the process to be fully automatic without the user interaction.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

p.s. my system setup is:

```
OS: Mac OS X 10.7.5
python: 2.7.1
scapy: 2.2.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just in case somebody else ran into the same issue, I managed to solve it by installing pypcap module to replace pcapy. I referred to http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.scapy.general/4026

you will need to have the following dependencies installed:

- C compiler + make (Xcode will have these settled)
- libpcap
- pyrex ( can be installed by package manager e.g., pip ).

you might run into an issue when you install `pypcap` after the dependencies are installed, refer to this patch http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/issues/detail?id=13, it worked for me!

Comment: Installing `pypcap` and restarting `scapy` was enough - it automatically used `pypcap` instead. Thanks!